# Two conditions with if functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me figure out the following:

Dependency on two cells to arrive at the results  E.g cell A2 is `today()` and cell a3 is null then result should be "add". If cell a2 is any backdate and cell A3 is null then result should be "pending". If cell a3 is not null then result should be "settled". Adding this "add" condition with A3 becomes difficult.

Comment: something like `=IF(A3=0,IF(A2=TODAY(),"add",IF(A2<TODAY(),"pending","")),"settled")`... is "null" a 0 or an empty string or an error???

Comment: @DirkReichel I'd say that qualifies as an answer instead of a comment...

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not sure if that is what the OP wanted... as suggested, I'll add it as an answer :)

```
=IF(A3=0,IF(A2=TODAY(),"add",IF(A2<TODAY(),"pending","")),"settled")
```